# Don't you think that a category system would be useful for Documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation

Let's say you choose a tag, for example [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) This tag has only categories in the Documentation, but each category has subcategories in [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css). Each subcategory need syntax and more examples.

What solution would be to keep everything organised now? Maybe keep only the subcategories, without the parent categories? It is this mentioned anywhere and I didn't see?